# Javascript - Search for whole words inside an array and create new array with coincidences

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

Having an `array` of arrays named `data` with following format:

```
> data[1].toString()
"Seed Keywords,disconnectors,EUR,210,0.03,,,,,N,Y,"
```

And another array named `groupKeywordsText` with a list of words to find inside the array data:

```
> console.log(groupKeywordsText);
["switch", "ac", "high", "switches", "disconnect", "voltage", "isolator"]
```

I need to create a set of new arrays that include only elements from `data` which contains a whole word from `groupKeywordsText`.

**SOME EXAMPLES:**

**An array can be assigned in only one of the new arrays:**

```
> data[3].toString()
"Keyword Ideas,ac,EUR,1900,0.00,1.58,,,,N,N,"
```

- Will be assigned to the **second** new array, because "ac" is exactly one of the searched term.

**An array can be assigned in multiple new arrays:**

```
> data[12].toString()
"Keyword Ideas,high voltage,EUR,27100,0.00,1.58,,,,N,N,"
```

- Will be assigned to the **third** new array, because "high side"
  contains the term to search: "high".
- Additionally, it will be included in the **5th** array, as "voltage" also appears.

**An array can be assigned in multiple new arrays, but not in others:**

```
> data[18].toString()
"Keyword Ideas,isolator for switch,EUR,1100,0.00,1.58,,,,N,N,"
```

- Will be assigned to the **first** new array, because "isolator for switch"
  contains the term to search: "switch".
- Additionally, it will be included in the **6th** array, as "isolator" also appears.
- However, it will not appear in the 4th array ("switches"), because we search for, and only exactly for, "switch".

**An array cannot be assigned in new arrays:**

```
> data[28].toString()
"Keyword Ideas,stackoverflow,EUR,1900,0.00,1.58,,,,N,N,"
```

- Wont be assigned to a new array, because "stackoverflow" isn't a searched term.

So far, my code looks like:

```
    for ( var i = 0, l = groupKeywordsText.length; i < l; i++ ) {

        keywordToSearch = groupKeywordsText[i];
        var length = data.length;
        this["keywordGroup"+i] = [];

                for(var j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                    if (data[j][1] == keywordToSearch) {
                    this["keywordGroup"+i].push(data[j][1]);
                    }
                }

        console.log(this["keywordGroup"+i]);
    }
```

How can I search for whole (not partial) words inside a string?

Comment: Your question is **VERY** unclear. Provide accurate input samples with matching output

Comment: Could you please show us the arrays as JSON, not the `.toString()` version of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search for whole words inside a string, you can use:

```
var myString = 'longStringWithLotsOfWords';
var word = 'String';
var noWord = 'StackOverflow';
myString.indexOf(word) != -1; //true, 'String' is inside myString
myString.indexOf(noWord) != -1; //false, 'StackOverflow' is not inside myString
```

If you have a string like

```
'firstValue,secondValue,thirdValue,Value'
```

and you want to exactly search for 'Value', you have can transform the string in an array using

```
var content = 'firstValue,secondValue,thirdValue,Value';
var contentAsArray = content.split('');
var hasElement = contentAsArray.indexOf('Value') != -1;
```

Note that this trick assumes that your words are separated by ','.

In your case, i think you can use it like. So you do not have to convert it to string and back to array again.

```
data[1].indexOf('wordThatYouWant')
```

Comment: Your answer helped a lot. First, I discovered the function .indexOf() which did the trickt. Second, it helped me realize, that I was not converting the array value to strings previos the comparision. However, after doublechecking the results, it appears that the result is not as expected, as arrays are created with elements that are not wanted (f.i. if searching for switch, there appears elements like switchgear or switches.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search only for whole words, so excluding "delight" when you are looking for "light", then you could use a regular expression with `\b` escapes inside.

Also, you'll need an additional loop, as your data structure has two dimensions.

Here is some code, turning the search words into a regular expression with `\b`:

```js
function test() {
    for ( var i = 0, l = groupKeywordsText.length; i < l; i++ ) {
        var keywordToSearch = groupKeywordsText[i];
        // Make regular expression for searching this keyword as whole word only.
        // The keyword might need some escaping so it does not conflict
        // with the regexp syntax:
        var re = new RegExp('\\b' + keywordToSearch.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + '\\b');
        this["keywordGroup"+i] = [];

        for(var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
            for(var k = 0; k < data[j].length; k++) {
                // test against the regular expression:
                if (data[j][k] && data[j][k].match(re)) {
                    this["keywordGroup"+i].push(data[j]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return this;
}

// Sample data
var data = [
    ["Seed Keywords", "disconnectors" ,"EUR", "210" , "0.03" ,,,,,"N","Y"],
    ["ac", "hello", "who's there", "time to switch the lights off"],
    ["electricity", "high voltage", "danger"],
    ["volt and ampère", "a switch turned on"],
];

var groupKeywordsText = ["switch", "ac", "high", "switches", "disconnect", "voltage", "isolator"];

// Call
var result = test.bind({})();

// Show result in snippet
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, null, 4) + '</pre>');
```